# SQL Connection String Format Error in Docker

Tags: sql-server, windows, docker

I am running a Docker container with a gMSA identity to connect to SQL Server via Windows Authentication. I confirmed the gMSA identity is working correctly within the container, however I'm receiving a SQL connection string format error:

"Format of the initialization string does not conform to specification starting at index 0."

My Dockerfile looks like this:

```
FROM microsoft/dotnet:2.2-runtime-nanoserver-sac2016
COPY . .
ENTRYPOINT ["dotnet", "Daemon.dll"]
CMD ["EventConfig:MqHostName=10.23.2.1", "ConnectionStrings:TestDb1=Data Source=10.23.2.1;Initial Catalog=Events;Integrated Security=true", "ConnectionStrings:TestDb2=Data Source=10.23.2.1;Initial Catalog=Notifications;Integrated Security=true", "ConnectionStrings:TestDb3=Data Source=10.23.2.1;Initial Catalog=TESTDB;Integrated Security=true"]
```

Running docker inspect on the container looks like the CMD parameters are parsed correctly, however I'm still receiving the error. The connection strings work without issue outside of Docker.

I've tried surrounding the connection strings by a backtick `, single quotes, double quotes, and slash . I've also tried passing in the strings as ENV variables instead of as CMD parameters. I've also tried adding a parser directive such as

```
# escape=`
```

to the top of my Dockerfile. Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For anyone who may have a similar issue, I determined how to escape the inner quotes using the `\` character. The correctly formatted Dockerfile connection strings looks like this:

```
CMD ["EventConfig:MqHostName=10.23.2.1", "ConnectionStrings:TestDb1\"=Data Source=10.23.2.1;Initial Catalog=Events;Integrated Security=true\"", "ConnectionStrings:TestDb2=\"Data Source=10.23.2.1;Initial Catalog=Notifications;Integrated Security=true\"", "ConnectionStrings:TestDb3=\"Data Source=10.23.2.1;Initial Catalog=TESTDB;Integrated Security=true\""]
```